# Control over popup windows using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, settimeout

I'm making a website for my girlfriend as a holiday gift. We both love art, code and music so yeah! 
I'm trying to make a website which has just one button/link and after it is clicked, the website starts playing music, opening and closing popup windows with some gifs and stuff as the music goes on. The problem is, i'm having a hard time applying a delay on my first popup window, it closes automatically but even after reading and trying code from other questions in this topic, I couldn't get the delay of the opening of the popup  to work right. Also, I couldn't get to place the popups in a specific position in the screen :(( this is what I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> pop ups </title>
<script>

var theURL = 'http://49.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3f88eRfVg1qcy0o0o1_500.gif';
var width  = 420;
var height = 315;

function popWindow() {
newWindow = window.open(theURL,'newWindow','toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,location=no,width='+width+',height='+height);


setTimeout(function() {
newWindow.close();
}, 3000)
} ;

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <p><a href="javascript:popWindow()"> temporalmente </a>      </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What isn't working? I tried your code, and it closes the window after 3 seconds.

Comment: Sorry I missed the bad part!!! I could get it to close after 3 seconds but I don't know how to delay its appereance for 5 seconds or so. I guess it's using the setTimeout function but I just can't get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delay opening the window, use another `setTimeout`

```
function popWindow() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var newWindow = window.open(theURL,'newWindow','toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,location=no,width='+width+',height='+height);

        setTimeout(function() {
            newWindow.close();
        }, 3000);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Barmar! it works, but I had to disable the option "block pop up windows" from the security preferences of Safari. It seems like Safari allows delay in auto-closing but not delay in the opening of a pop up (without disabling the block popups option). Is there any way of linking the closing of the first popup (without delay) to a next popup? like: When the first popup is closed, a new one appears automatically

Comment: The way that the browser tells the difference between wanted and unwanted popups is that wanted popups happen while it's running an event handler. When you delay the popup with a timeout, it's no longer directly linked with the original event, and the browser thinks it's adware trying to get around the block.

Comment: What you describe is exactly what adware tries to do, and is why browsers have implemented these counter-measures. Adware would pop up an ad, and when you closed it a new ad would pop up in its place, and you could never get rid of them.

Comment: If your girlfriend trusts you, she should turn off her popup blocker on your site. If she won't, then maybe you should reconsider the relationship. :)

Comment: hahahaha yeah I guess i'll do that! it's just that I have been in a website which does that thing of the pop ups before... I just can't remember the name... I'll comment it here when I get the link.. I have learned a lot! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So I am testing out your code here and it seems to be working fine.  Perhaps the issue could be with the browser you are using.  Try your code out in google chrome and the delay should work.  In regards to the pop up location in the page, you want to add a top and left property with a number value to the third argument to window.open.  Something like:

```
...',height='+height + ', left=500, top=500')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm using Safari 9.0 and the closing part works fine, but still I need some help with the delay of the appearance, like, I click the link and after 3 seconds a pop up window appear and disappear after 3 more seconds.. I want to do this with several windows/links